# Manga/anime about a mage who makes himself younger but in the process falls asleep for 100 years

Tags: story-identification, manga, anime

It's this one anime I watched not long ago.

There is this old mage who drinks a certain potion to make himself younger. Once he drinks the potion he gets put to sleep and sleeps for like 100 years more or less. When he wakes up he looks in the mirror noticing how much younger he looks. He leaves his bunker and finds out his whole laboratory is gone and that the world looks different.

He then goes out to explore the world and comes across a few people who need help with their carriage because their wheel broke. He then thinks to himself “A carriage?”. He uses creation magic to fix the wheel. After he fixes the wheel, he wants to find out why civilization is devolving because carriages weren’t being used before he fell asleep.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is *[Kiwameta Renkinjutsu ni, Fukanou wa Nai.: Bannou Skill de Isekai Musou](https://myanimelist.net/manga/148087)*, a manga from 2022. I can't find any sign of an anime adaptation. But I did find some results on youtube for the title, I assume of people just making videos of manga panels.

> "There's still more to do, that's why I need more time."
>
> With a strong determination, the **old man picked up his rejuvenation potion**. The secret of this particular potion is that it rejuvenates the body while preserving the person's memory. Essentially the fountain of youth. The old man took it anyways and it took a while for the potion to tale effect. **Five hundred years passed**... The man, or young boy at this moment, awoke and found himself in the same world yet different. **Nations disappeared, Regression of Civilization, decline in human skills and even basic alchemy has been lost**! Lost Knowledge, Lost Technology! Nothing impossible in the mastery of alchemy!

The main character is an old man alchemist researcher. He is over 100 years old and uses potions to stay alive, but realizes he's at the end of their use and uses a stronger elixir to regain his youth. This results in him sleeping for 500 years, during which time his laboratory and the entire city it was based in disappears.

[image: 500 years later, forest instead of city]

He goes out to explore and finds a carriage that's stuck, and realizes that civilization has regressed, as no one used carriages still in his time.

[image: Finding a carriage in the future]

He fixes the wheel of the carriage by regrowing the damaged wood. The term "creation magic" isn't explicitly used, but it's the same idea.